# Stripe - Applying a discount to a new subscription item on an existing subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

We charge our customers monthly with a single subscription per customer. That subscription can have one or many subscription items, if the customer is paying for many accounts with different products. We want to offer a 3 month discounts for new accounts set up by new and existing customers.

For existing Customers, adding a new account means adding a new subscription item to the existing subscription. **In Stripe, is there a way to apply a discount/promocode to a single subscription items within a subscription?**

In the docs it talks about applying a code to a Customer vs a Subscription, but I can't find anything about the subscription item level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an out-of-the-box approach for discounting particular items within a Subscription.

You could build a solution using Subscription Schedules to stage changes to a Subscription. This would allow you to start the Subscription Item at one price (the discounted amount), and then use the Subscription Schedule to schedule an adjustment to that Subscription Item that changes the price it is using to the normal price.
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules